# how to customise the Google Recaptcha widget?

Tags: html, iframe, recaptcha

I would like to be able to change the text that displays: "I'm not a robot" to something else, but using JQuery I cannot access the inner span element to change the .html.

The problem is the iFrame name and id changes each time and there is inline google script which must be doing this inside the iFrame.

I am using the widget inside a user control and have an instance of this on my webform in a content page and it otherwise works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible.

The iframe from their domain cannot be edited and the API allows for no such customization.

Comment: Ok, I thought so.

But, why not?
Surely, if the browser has downloaded the page and the de-bugger is showing the DOM with all the element id's and classes shown in the de-bugger, why can't script then manipulate these elements?

Are you saying that iFrames generated with third party scripts embedded in this way, are read-only ?

Comment: @PaulKersey Here's some reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy Since the iframe comes from a different domain, or origin, it is inaccessible.